# How do I nest a scss rule for one specific selector in a list using &

Tags: css, sass

I have a question that I could not find in the documentation or by searching stack overflow.

This is not the best example but it will give you the gist of what I am trying to accomplish.

**Example**

```
  .btn-group { 

   .btn { 
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    &.btn-danger {
      background-color: red;
    }
    &.btn-primary {
      background-color: blue; 
    }

    &.btn-primary, &.btn-danger {
      box-shadow: 1px solid black;
      &[0] {
        border: 10px solid black;
      }
    }

    }

  }
```

Is there a way to select only one of the elements in a list? Maybe using array notation or something of that manner?

This does not work, but you can see what I am trying to accomplish.

**Demo**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awjeON

**The real world example**

```
  .bounce {

    .ng-leave {
      display: none; 
    }

    .ng-enter, .ng-leave {
      position: relative;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-duration: 1s;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use nth-child.

```
&:nth-child(1) {
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: I should have thought about nth-child! 

Thanks Jennifer. I'll mark this complete in a couple minutes.

Comment: @dotKn0ck glad to help!